# ADAMS/View - how to plot part orientation?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, software

it is a simple question but I am new to this software. Both in *Postprocessor* and within *Measure Characteristic* options there are only angular velocities and accelerations - and no angle (orientation) itself. I saw *Angle* and *Orientation Measure* options but this must be something more advanced, since all I need is generalised coordinate of a part.

Also, is it possible to obtain set of generalised coords against time in table form instead of plot? If so, please explain how.

Thank you in advance,

Maverick

Comment: I feel sorry for you, having to use ADAMS. Anyway, I think you setup a request using the `AX()`, `AY()` or `AZ()` function to measure angles along axes.

Comment: @ja72 no need to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You can export a Adams/Solver dataset (.adm) that will contain all the variables that were solved in a ascii format. (file export)
- you can export a results file.
- You can also export measures in the post processor as a ascii tabular data. In the file export dialog in case you want to specify what format the measure is to be had in.

Comment: I havent got adams licenses anymore so i cant test for time being.